# Why client.dart in route use gotopath rather than handle?

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart-html

I asked to fix an issue in software which use dart to develop a chrome application. currently, the chrome application doesn't run in my mac osx and I get the following exception:

Uncaught Unhandled exception:
Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap' has no instance method 'pushState'.

```
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'pushState'
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:0
Arguments: [null, "", "/index.html#events"]
#0      Object._noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:42)
#1      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#2      Router._go (package:route/client.dart:153:22)
#3      Router.gotoPath (package:route/client.dart:139:7)
#4      Router.listen.<anonymous closure> (package:route/client.dart:111:13)
#5      wrap_event_listener.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:html:1189)VM81:1 (anonymous function)
```

After I backtrace the issue, I found that listen() function instead of calling handle calls gotoPath(string,string). Can someone explain me that. this cause

[https://github.com/justinfagnani/route/blob/master/lib/client.dart][1]

```
void gotoPath(String path, String title) {
    _logger.finest('gotoPath $path');
    var url = _getUrl(path);
    if (url != null) {
      _go(path, title);
      // If useFragment, onHashChange will call handle for us.
      if (!_listen || !useFragment) {
        _handlers[url](path);
      }
    }
  }

void handle(String path) {
    _logger.finest('handle $path');
    var url = _getUrl(path);
    if (url != null) {
      // always give handlers a non-fragment path
      var fixedPath = url.reverse(url.parse(path));
      _handlers[url](fixedPath);
    } else {
      _logger.info("Unhandled path: $path");
    }
  }
```

this calls from here: 
Note that other methods if/else call `handle` and only the `!ignoreclick` is call `gotopath`

```
void listen({bool ignoreClick: false}) {
    _logger.finest('listen ignoreClick=$ignoreClick useFragment=$useFragment');
    if (_listen) {
      throw new StateError('listen should be called once.');
    }
    _listen = true;
    if (useFragment) {
      window.onHashChange.listen((_) {
        var path = '${window.location.pathname}${window.location.hash}';
        _logger.finest('onHashChange handle($path)');
        return handle(path);
      });
      handle('${window.location.pathname}${window.location.hash}');
    } else {
      window.onPopState.listen((_) {
        var path = '${window.location.pathname}${window.location.hash}';
        _logger.finest('onPopState handle($path)');
        handle(path);
      });
    }
    if (!ignoreClick) {
      window.onClick.listen((e) {
        if (e.target is AnchorElement) {
          AnchorElement anchor = e.target;
          if (anchor.host == window.location.host) {
            var fragment = (anchor.hash == '') ? '' : '${anchor.hash}';
            gotoPath("${anchor.pathname}$fragment", anchor.title);
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this in Chrome or Dartium? What versions?  I think there was a bug report recently. Don't have to the time just now to look it up.

Comment: Dartium, I can send pull request probably and you merge it. the fix is simple, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Probably better to discuss it with the Dart team first. Looks similar to https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/16963. If you think it's different, just create a new issue.